# CoinBase - getProductHistoricRates gives me invalid interval

Tags: node.js, coinbase-api

I'm sending:

```
var startTime = moment().subtract(7, 'days');
var endTime = moment();
var granularity = 60 * 60 * 24;
var args = {'start':startTime, 'end':endTime, 'granularity':granularity};

publicClient.getProductHistoricRates(args, function(err, response, data) {
  console.log('data: ', data);
});
```

I'm receiving:

> data:  { message: 'Invalid interval' }

startTime and endTime formatted:

> startTime:  2016-01-30T19:06:05+00:00 , endTime:  2016-02-06T19:06:05+00:00

I want 7 candles, each with the high and low for the day.  How do I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake:

```
var args = {'start':startTime, 'end':endTime, 'granularity':granularity};
```

should be:

```
var args = {'start':startTime.format(), 'end':endTime.format(), 'granularity':granularity};
```